# identical id don't recognized on javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i will try to go straight to the point. I'm building a integration with html form to google sheets. The concepct works fine, i just have one problem: I have two forms on my pages (many of them). With many testing results, i've found out that the problem is that my javascript takes only the ID tag from the input on HTML.

So, i can't use identical id's, i know that, but only one of my forms work! I've been testing this for hours. Can anybody help me?

The only explanation i found is that my code only read the ID tag. So i see two paths:

1. I use some alternative tag to ID, that i could use on both forms;
2. There is some way (that i don't know) to insert into this javascript code some lines and force my code to accept duplicate id's or something like that.

Below is some example: One of my forms and the javascript part that search for the variables. I don't know much of javascript, so i beg for your help!

```js
function submit_form() {    
// Check Fields
var complete = true;
var error_color = '#FFD9D9';
var fields = ['nome','email','telefone'];
var row = '';
var i;
for(i=0; i < fields.length; ++i) {
    var field = fields[i];
    $('#'+field).css('backgroundColor', 'inherit');
    var value = $('#'+field).val();       
    // Validate Field
    if(!value) {
        if(field != 'message') {
            $('#'+field).css('backgroundColor', error_color);
            var complete = false;
        }
        } else {            
  // Sheet Data
        row += '"'+value+'",';
    }
}
   
// Submission
if(complete) {  
 // Clean Row
 row = row.slice(0, -1);  
    // Config
    var gs_sid = ''; // Enter your Google Sheet ID here
    var gs_clid = '306153877656-sbedffh19uommvljmns11ji28ckdj7g0.apps.googleusercontent.com'; // Enter your API Client ID here
    var gs_clis = ''; // Enter your API Client Secret here
    var gs_rtok = ''; // Enter your OAuth Refresh Token here
    var gs_atok = false;
    var gs_url = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/'+gs_sid+'/values/A1:append?includeValuesInResponse=false&insertDataOption=INSERT_ROWS&responseDateTimeRenderOption=SERIAL_NUMBER&responseValueRenderOption=FORMATTED_VALUE&valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED';
    var gs_body = '{"majorDimension":"ROWS", "values":[['+row+']]}';        
     // HTTP Request Token Refresh
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?client_id='+gs_clid+'&client_secret='+gs_clis+'&refresh_token='+gs_rtok+'&grant_type=refresh_token');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function() {            
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var gs_atok = response.access_token;            
  // HTTP Request Append Data
        if(gs_atok) {
            var xxhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xxhr.open('POST', gs_url);
            xxhr.setRequestHeader('Content-length', gs_body.length);
            xxhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
            xxhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + gs_atok );
            xxhr.onload = function() {
    if(xxhr.status == 200) {
     // Success
     $('#message').html('<p>Row Added to Sheet | <a href="http://snydergroupinc.com/tutorials/tutorial-google-sheets-api.php">Add Another &raquo;</a></p><p>Response:<br/>'+xxhr.responseText+'</p>');
     } else {
     // Fail
     $('#message').html('<p>Row Not Added</p><p>Response:<br/>'+xxhr.responseText+'</p>');
    }
            };
            xxhr.send(gs_body);
        }            
    };
    xhr.send();
}
}
```

```html
<form id="sheets33" name="sheets33" class="contact-form row" method="post" action="c_form/envia.php">
     
     
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label></label>
                            <input id="nome" name="nome" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira seu nome">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label></label>
                            <input id="email" name="email"  value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira seu email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label></label>
                            <input id="telefone" name="telefone" value="" class="form-control " placeholder="Insira seu telefone">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label></label>
                            <textarea name="mensagem" class="form-control" rows="9" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                            <label></label>
       
       <input type="hidden" class="form-control" placeholder="Origem" name="Origem" value="<?php echo $_GET["origem"]; ?>">
                            <button style="border-color:#000000" id="submit2" value="Submit" name="submit2" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" onClick="submit_form()">
       <span style="color:#000000">Enviar<i class="ion-android-arrow-forward"></i></span></button>
       
       
       
       
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Duplicate IDs are forbidden in HTML. So go with option 1.

Comment: Is not as simple as that. Could you really help me with that?

Answer (score 3):

Ids are meant to be unique, so if you need to target multiple elements you should use a class, or consider setting a `data-form-id` attribute on the element that you can target.

So if you have:

```
<form data-form-id="33">...
```

Your Javascript can target it like this:

```
$("form[data-form-id='" + field +"']");
```

This assumes you're using `jQuery`, but it's possible with vanilla Javascript as well.

Comment: Nick, i've edited the javascript code. When i use anything rather than "ID" on the tag, it don't send to sheets. I've made this modification on the javascript code, but it didn't work as well.

And by the way, i'm just editing the file on Notepad++. This .js file don't appear to have anything forcing it to read only the ID tag, so i'm still in trouble ;/

Answer (score 1):

Use some other selector like `name` attribute or a `class`

```
$('input[name='+field+']')
```

Id cannot be reused. Should be unique.

Comment: i've tried, but seems like the .js code (i've edited the post with the full .js code) don't accept nothing different than the ID. I'm still trying something to change this, but nothing works yet...

Comment: `$('#'+field).css('backgroundColor', 'inherit');`  needs to be replaced with `$('input[name='+field+']').css('backgroundColor', 'inherit');` .

Comment: I've changed it, and nothing changed still. Like Soren said, i think it is the .val atribute too, or i need to change the "id" attribute. Will try it now.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see the problem is not the selection of the elements but the processing of the values.

`$('#'+field)` selects all elements with the matching id but `css()` and `val()` both select only the first element of the found set.

[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
Get the current value of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the value of every matched element.
```

[.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
Get the value of a computed style property for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more CSS properties for every matched element.
```

Best would be like recomending by the others to avoid duplicated ids. But if you can't avoid it you have to iterate over the result set and collect the data for each element itself. You can use a classic for loop or the jQuery [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function.

To prevent duplicated IDs you could write an ID generator or if your form ids are unique you could prefix your field ids with the form id.

Comment: Your answer are really good. Like i said, i don't know too much of Javascript. I will try to understand this .each function, but what you recommend me to do right now, to make it work?

It makes sense that the .val and .css takes the first element they see, because the working form comes first on the code. I've identified the problem, but still i don't have all de knowledge i wish i had to modify it.

If you can keep helping me, i thank you really much! If you can't, i understand. Thanks for identifying the problem, i will try my best to fix it today.

Comment: I still don't know how should i replace .val function.

Comment: You can use .map().Would look like `var values = $('#'+field).map(function(fielEl){return jQuery(fielEl).val();})`. You will get an array with all values of all fields. From there on you can iterate over it with a normal for-loop